# Remove item Content Type from custom list

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, visual-studio, custom-list

I have created through Visual Studio a Content Type that inherits from Item and a custom list using this content type. What I would like is to remove the item content type that appears when creating a new item.

More precisely, this option here:

[image]

Any way to achieve this through Visual Studio so it appears in every instance?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the List Settings page for your list, scroll down to the Content Types section, click on the link 'Change new button order and default content type', and on the following page uncheck 'Visible' for the Item content type.  It will no longer be visible in the new item ribbon menu.

Comment: Thank you Dylan, but I want to achieve this programmatically so this can be reflected in any instance of that list. I will update this questions with this

Answer (score 1):

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://pbmossdev"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        string listName = "New List";
        string listDescription = "Test content types on lists";

        Guid listId = web.Lists.Add(listName,
            listDescription,
            SPListTemplateType.GenericList);

        SPList myList = web.Lists[listId];

        myList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
        myList.ContentTypes.Add(web.AvailableContentTypes["Contact"]);//Replace with your custom content type
        myList.ContentTypes.Delete( myList.ContentTypes["Item"].Id  );

        myList.Update();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where would this be placed?

Comment: In feature event receiver on feature activated.For information on how to create list on feature activated, refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548874/automatically-creating-a-list-and-a-folder-when-activating-a-feature-in-sharepoi

Comment: Also, if you do not want to change settings by code, you can do list settings as per @Dylan suggested, then save it as template and add to solution. Then, in feature receiver, instead of SPListTemplateType.GenericList, create list from this template which you have saved.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this alternative and let you know the outcome!

Comment: Actually, I was just looking at the code, and what I need is that any custom list with a particular content type, does not have content type Item available. Is a feature the right way to go?

Comment: Custom list is already available or has to be created through code?What this code does is: 1)Create a custom list 2) Associate custom content type 3) Remove Item Content Type.

Comment: I created an instance through code, but users will eventually create new ones from that template, so this needs to be applied to any instance. Makes sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21646/discussion-between-404-and-gonzalo).

Answer (score 0):

Would you like a PowerShell solution for your query? Once you deploy your wsp package you can run a Tiding up PowerShell script which can take care of all such requirements. Make a PowerShell script file, and write all the functional logic which you want to achieve on top of wsp package. Removing content type can be one of it.

> Below is a server side PowerShell script which will remove ITEM content type from the list

```
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
    $web = Get-SPWeb "UrlOfYourSite"
    $list = $web.Lists["YourListName"]
    $ctToRemove = $list.ContentTypes["Item"]
    if($ctToRemove)
    {
        Write-Host "Removing Item content type"
        $list.ContentTypes.Delete($ctToRemove.Id)
        $list.Update()
        $Web.Dispose()
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Item content type do not exists in list"
    }
```